# Segmentation fault when trying to read hidden files linux

Tags: c, linux, pointers, malloc, realloc

My program reads the content of a directory specified at command line. It reads the directory recursively i.e. if we are reading contents of directory "test" and inside it we have another directory "inside", then it will also read the content of the directory named "inside". The issue is it works fine if i do not read hidden directories i.e. directories that start with "." . But in case i read hidden directories too it says Segmentation fault.

The code is as below:

The main file:

```
#include "helper.h"

/*
 * Display's content of String array passed to it,
 * that should conatin full path to files.
 */
void display(char **);

/*
 * Free's the memory utilized by the program
 */
void cleanup(char **);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s [dir]\n\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char **files = calloc(1, sizeof(char *));

    // get files from the directory specified
    getFiles(&files, argv[1]);

    // display files
    display(files);

    // free memory utilized by files array
    cleanup(files);

// that's all folks
return 0;
}


/*
 * Display's content of String array passed to it,
 * that should conatin full path to files.
 */
void display(char **files)
{
    // Color Red
//  printf("[0;31;40m");

    // display files
    for (int i = 0; files[i]; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", files[i]);
    }

    // turn off color
//  printf("[0;37;40m");
}


/*
 * Free's the memory utilized by the program
 */
void cleanup(char **files)
{
    // free memory utilized by files array
    for (int i = 0; files[i]; i++)
        free(files[i]);
    free(files);
}
```

The getFiles function is defined in helpers.c file which contain the following code as below:

```
#include "helper.h"
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

/*
 * Stores the list of files present in direectory pointed by 'dir' 
 * in array of strings pointed by 'files'
 */
void getFiles(char ***files, const char* dir)
{
    static int i;

    // ensure directory is valid
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Invalid Directory\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // declare and initialize directory handler
    DIR *dd = opendir(dir);
    if (dd == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Directory Not Found\n\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    // structure that store file attributes read
    struct dirent *content;

    // read directory until all files are scanned
    while ((content = readdir(dd)) != NULL)
    {
        // ignore '.' and '..' directories
        if (strcmp(content->d_name, ".") == 0 || 
            strcmp(content->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        /*if (content->d_name[0] == '.')
            continue;*/

        //store full file path from current directory
        char temp[1024] = {0};

        // make full path
        makepath(temp, dir, content->d_name);

        // recall itself if another directory found
        if (isdir(temp))
        {
            // read this new directory found
            getFiles(files, temp);
            continue;
        }

        // allocate memory to store locations of char *
        *files = realloc(*files, (i + 2)*(sizeof(char *)));

        // allocate heap memory and store location
        *(*(files + 0) + i) = (char *)strdup(temp);

        // move to next location
        i++;
    }

    // free directory handler
    closedir(dd);

    // set NULL after last file name
    *(*(files + 0) + i) = '\0';
}


/*
 * returns true if 'dir' refers to a directory, false otherwise
 */
bool isdir(const char * dir)
{
    DIR *temp;
    temp = opendir(dir);

    if (temp != NULL)
    {
        closedir(temp);
        return true;
    }

return false;
}


/*
 * appends dir and file/directory name to src, 
 * thus makes a full file/directory path, from current directory
 */
void makepath(char src[], const char *dir, const char *file)
{   
    // prepend directory name
    strcat(src, dir);
    strcat(src, "/");

    // append file/directory name
    strcat(src, file);
}
```

Necessary header files are included by me in helper.h file.

Also i wanted to know am i making mistake in memory allocation. (In realloc in getFiles Function).

Ignore hidden files line is commented by me at this time.

```
/*if (content->d_name[0] == '.')
                continue;*/
```

If i uncomment the above line then program works fine.

If you are thinking why i am storing file names as read by readdir function, because those names are necessary for  me later so that is why i am not right away displaying the file names.

Any suggestion how i can better implement this program and also how to fix the issue that occurs when i read hidden directories.

Comment: Looks like an endless loop. Can you print out the directory names, this might give you a clue what the program is doing.

Comment: Would you care to point to the line where segmentation fault erorr is ocurring

Comment: Your recursive call ignores and destroys all entries that the caller has already collected. (it also might run out of filedescriptors for the DIR) Better use a queue for the subdirs. oops, now I see that the i is static.

Comment: Do you see any other programatical errors, as it is only failing in one test case i think it is because that directory contains lot of files as i am trying to get a list of files in my users home directory. Can that be a reason? and this much of recursion causes error.

Comment: It gives Segfault only when i try to list my home directory in linux which contain lot of folders, so i am quite sure it is because of heavy recursion other wise it works fine on other directories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's the problem but here:

```
// set NULL after last file name
*(*(files + 0) + i) == '\0';

                     ^ you are not setting to NULL, you are comparing
```

Comment: sorry for that typo and thnks for noticing

Comment: Do you see any other programatical errors, as it is only failing in one test case i think it is because that directory contains lot of files as i am trying to get a list of files in my users home directory. Can that be a reason? and this much of recursion causes error.